# get audio playlist from soundcloud

Tags: html, audio, soundcloud

I have html5 audio player written using soundmanager2.

In my jquery I would need to get track urls and titles for my player from the link like this:

http://soundcloud.com/officialswedishhousemafia/sets/rootmusic-bandpage

or this for example:

http://gidilounge.fm/?feed=podcast

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the SoundCloud JavaScript SDK (which incidentally includes soundManager2 for streaming support). If all you have is the set URL, you could use the resolve endpoint to get an id and a proper representation of the resource:

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'foo'
});

var set_url = "http://soundcloud.com/officialswedishhousemafia/sets/rootmusic-bandpage";
SC.get('/resolve', { url: track_url }, function(set) {
  $(set.tracks).each(function(i, track) {
     console.log(track.title);
  });
});
```

That should allow you to get all the information about tracks that you need.

Answer (score 1):

SoundCloud has an open API: http://developers.soundcloud.com/

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks! what about this other link? (http://gidilounge.fm/?feed=podcast) if i go to view source, this is an xml file. how do i read this xml file?